# Set number of decimals in all textviews

Tags: android

In my app I use a lot of decimal numbers. I show numbers in lots of TextViews but I want to display those numbers with 2 decimal places.
Is there a way to set this number of decimals to all TextViews, like a global instruction or something? Or the only possible way is formating each of my string before calling the TextView.text() function?

Thanks, Direz

Comment: I don't think there is a global setting. You need to set it for each textview AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write yourself a subclass of TextView and override the setText() method so that it applies the format for you. That way you only have to put the String format logic in one place and it will get applied to all of your views. The downside is though you'll have to switch all of the TextViews in your app to your own version.